# How can I live stream a VR game developed with Unity on my website using React.js, for example?

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, websocket, stream, webrtc

How can I live stream a VR game developed with Unity C# on my website using React.js and node.js, for example?

I tried using webRTC for that but I don't know specially what to do. If anyone have some ideas it would be helpull.

Comment: The simplest solution should be FMETP STREAM, via node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this Unity package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.renderstreaming@3.1/manual/index.html). It's called *Render Streaming* and does exactly what it says on the tin - it uses WebRTC under the hood to stream to a connected peer.

It's still tagged as *experimental*, so expect possible API changes, but I use it in a project to stream VR content and it works pretty well all in all.

And it comes with [samples](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.renderstreaming@3.1/manual/samples.html) (and a preconfigured [Node.js server](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.renderstreaming@3.1/manual/webapp.html) you can adapt).